# Quero ordernar um resultado aritimetico dentro do meu foreach. Como faço?

Tags: php, laravel

```
foreach($cotacaos as $cot){
    $percentual_cotacao = $cot->percentual_cotacao;
    $taxa_extra         = $cot->valor_extra;      
 
    $v1_calculo = $valor + ($valor * $percentual_cotacao * 0.01) + $taxa_extra;  
    $v2_calculo    = $valor - $v1_calculo;
    $calculo = $v2_calculo * -1;

    echo "<pre> Valor cotação: R$ ".number_format($calculo, 2, ',', '.')."</pre>";
       
    }    
    
}
```

Esse é o resultado do meu array: Preciso ordenar pelo valor da variável $cotacao.

Valor cotação: R$ 26,31

Valor cotação: R$ 46,11

Valor cotação: R$ 28,49

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Um sort($cotacaos) antes dessa função ai ja resolve brother :)

Se precisar de uma olhada nisso aqui que pode te ajudar!

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
sort($cotacaos);  // transforma os elementos do array de números em ordem crescente

foreach($cotacaos as $cot){
   $percentual_cotacao = $cot->percentual_cotacao;
   $taxa_extra         = $cot->valor_extra;      
   $v1_calculo = $valor + ($valor * $percentual_cotacao * 0.01) + $taxa_extra;  
   $v2_calculo    = $valor - $v1_calculo;
   $calculo = $v2_calculo * -1;

  echo "<pre> Valor cotação: R$ ".number_format($calculo, 2, ',', '.')."</pre>";
 }
}
```

Mostrando a ideia que foi sugerida no código. Espero que possa ajudar alguém!